# Need a simple messaging or queuing solution for logging to a web service

Tags: web-services, grails, message-queue

I've got a Grails app (version 2.2.4) with a controller method that "logs" all requests to an external web service (JSON over HTTP - one way message, response is not needed). I want to decouple the controller method from calling the web service directly/synchronously and provide a simple "queue" which can store the calls if the web service is unavailable and then send them through once the service is back up again.

This sounds like a good fit for some sort of JMS solution but I've not got any experience with using JMS (so learning curve could be an issue). Should I be using one of the [available messaging plugins](http://grails.org/plugins/tag/messaging) or is that overkill for my simple requirements? I don't want a separate messaging app, it has to be embedded in my webapp and I'd prefer something small and simple vs more complicated and robust (so advice on which plugin would be welcome).

The alternative is to implement an async service myself and queue the "messages" in the database (reading them via a Quartz job) or with something like java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

<strike>EDIT: Another approach could be to use log4j with a custom appender set up as a AsyncAppender.</strike>

Comment: Does the method that logs all the request have to persist the queue if the application crashes. (Resume from where it left off?)

Comment: No its not essential but would be nice to have. We are just logging some stats and user details so if we lose a few messages due to an app crash, we can live with that. My simple vs robust comment suggested this but I should've been explicit.

Comment: FYI this A was helpful but doesn't address my particular issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17646762/249327

Answer (score 0):

> The alternative is to implement an async service myself and queue the "messages" in the database (reading them via a Quartz job)

I went ahead and tried this approach. It was very straight forward and was only a "screen" length of code in the end. I tested it with a failing web service end point as well as an app restart (crash) and it handled both. I used a single service class to both persist the messages (Grails domain class) and to flush the queue (triggered by Quartz scheduler) which reads the DB and fires off the web service calls, removing the DB entity when web service returns 200 status code.